# Attempting to add objects to active scene in Unity, but objects load in parent scene

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to build a simple flying game. I have two scenes- a Management scene to spawn GameManager and SceneController instances, and a Game scene that is loaded where the player can fly through some red gates.

**Once the game scene is loaded additively, I add some gates to it. However, the gates don't show up under this scene in the hierarchy- they show up under the management scene.** The prefab does show up in the game scene. I would expect all of these to show up under the game scene.

Two questions:

1. Am I loading the game scene improperly? Does something else need to happen to make it fully active?
2. Do I not understand how scenes work, and if so, what should I be doing differently?

---

SceneController code:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class SceneController : MonoBehaviour {

    // This is a singleton
    private static SceneController _instance;

    public static SceneController Instance { get { return _instance; } }

    private void Awake()
    {
        if (_instance != null && _instance != this)
        {
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
        } else {
            _instance = this;
        }
    }

    // Scene names
    private string sceneNameGameScene = "GameScene";

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        SceneManager.sceneLoaded += OnSceneLoaded;
        StartCoroutine(LoadSceneAdditive(sceneNameGameScene, LoadSceneMode.Additive));
    }

    void OnSceneLoaded(Scene scene, LoadSceneMode mode) {
        if (scene.name == sceneNameGameScene) {
            SceneManager.SetActiveScene(scene);
            Debug.Log("OnSceneLoaded Active Scene : " + SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
            SetupGameScene();
        }
    }

    IEnumerator LoadSceneAdditive(string sceneName, LoadSceneMode loadSceneMode){
        AsyncOperation _async = new AsyncOperation();
        _async = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(sceneName, loadSceneMode);

        while (!_async.isDone) {
            yield return null;
        }

        Scene nextScene = SceneManager.GetSceneByName( name );
        if (nextScene.IsValid ()) {
            SceneManager.SetActiveScene (nextScene);
        }
    }


    private void SetupGameScene() {

        // Create a game map
        GameMap gameMap = new GameMap();
        gameMap.Setup(this.transform);
    }
}
```

GameMap Code:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class GameMap {
    private GameObject gatePrefab = GameObject.Instantiate(Resources.Load("GatePrefab")) as GameObject;
    private Transform transform;

    public GameMap() {}

    public void Setup (Transform parentTransform) {
        transform = parentTransform;
        Vector3 position;
        Quaternion rotation;

        position = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        rotation = Quaternion.identity;
        CreateGate(position, rotation, 10.0f, 2.0f, "Gate 1");

        position = new Vector3(0, 0, 20);
        rotation =  Quaternion.identity * Quaternion.Euler(0, 45, 0);
        CreateGate(position, rotation, 10.0f, 1.0f, "Gate 2");

        position = new Vector3(20, 0, 20);
        rotation =  Quaternion.identity * Quaternion.Euler(0, 90, 0);
        CreateGate(position, rotation, 8.0f, 1.0f, "Gate 3");

        CreateGround();
    }

    private void CreateGate(Vector3 position, Quaternion rotation, float lengthOfSide, float thickness, string name) {
        // Create the gates, and call the "Initialize" method to populate properties as Unity doesn't have constructors.
        GameObject clone = GameObject.Instantiate(gatePrefab, position, rotation, transform) as GameObject;
        clone.name = name;
        clone.GetComponent<Gate>().Initialize(lengthOfSide, thickness);
    }

    private void CreateGround() {
        Debug.Log("OnSceneLoaded Active Scene : " + SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
        GameObject ground = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Plane);
        ground.name = "Ground";
        ground.transform.parent = transform;
        ground.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0, -10, 0);
        ground.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.identity;
        ground.transform.localScale = new Vector3(50, 1, 50);

        ground.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.grey;
    }
}
```

Gate code:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Gate : MonoBehaviour {
    float lengthOfSide;
    float thickness;

    public void Initialize (float lengthOfSide, float thickness) {
        this.lengthOfSide = lengthOfSide;
        this.thickness = thickness;
    }

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        SetupRigidBody();
        Setup3dEntities();
    }

    void SetupRigidBody() {
        Rigidbody rb = this.gameObject.AddComponent<Rigidbody>();
        rb.detectCollisions = true;
        rb.mass = 1000;
        rb.useGravity = false;
    }

    // Create the physical gate
    void Setup3dEntities() {
        Vector3 position;
        Vector3 scale;
        float lengthOfVeritcalSegment = lengthOfSide - (2 * thickness);
        float yPosHorizontalSegment = (lengthOfSide - thickness) / 2;
        float xPosVerticalSegment = lengthOfSide - thickness;

        // Bottom
        position = new Vector3(0, -yPosHorizontalSegment, 0);
        scale = new Vector3(lengthOfSide, thickness, thickness);
        CreatePrimitiveCube(position, scale);

        // Top
        position = new Vector3(0, yPosHorizontalSegment, 0);
        scale = new Vector3(lengthOfSide, thickness, thickness);
        CreatePrimitiveCube(position, scale);

        // Left
        position = new Vector3(xPosVerticalSegment/2, 0, 0);
        scale = new Vector3(thickness, lengthOfVeritcalSegment, thickness);
        CreatePrimitiveCube(position, scale);

        // Right
        position = new Vector3(-xPosVerticalSegment/2, 0, 0);
        scale = new Vector3(thickness, lengthOfVeritcalSegment, thickness);
        CreatePrimitiveCube(position, scale);
    }

    void CreatePrimitiveCube(Vector3 position, Vector3 scale) {
        // Create a primitive cube. Note that we want to set the position and rotation to match the parent!
        GameObject cube = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
        cube.transform.parent = gameObject.transform;
        cube.transform.localPosition = position;
        cube.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.identity;
        cube.transform.localScale = scale;

        // TODO: Make a better color/material mechanism!
        cube.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.red;

//      Debug.Log("Cube.parent: " + cube.transform.parent.gameObject.name);
//      Debug.Log("Cube.localScale: " + cube.transform.localScale);
    }
}
```

Screenshot- note hierarchy is weird:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SceneController passes it's transform to the GameMap Setup method.
(I assume that the SceneController transform is the "app" object?)

The GameMap Setup method then creates the gates and uses the given parentTransform
as a parent for each gate (because it's passend in the GameObject.Instantiate method)

So i guess it makes sense that the Gate objects are a child of the "app" object which is in the managment scene?

If you want to have them in the other scene, then you have to pass a different parent or no parent.

Comment: Not passing in the parent appears to fix things. I was originally organizing my scene differently, and passing the in the parent was my newb solution.

Answer (score 0):

So, as i understand, you want to have a Managment Scene, where you can manage the game with a script.

My idea is that you dont use `LoadSceneAdditive` but [DontDestroyOnLoad](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html). This will make your script still be loaded even when you load an another scene. This will also make the gameobjects spawn in the currently loaded scene.

So, you will only have to use `LoadSceneMode.Single` instead of `LoadSceneMode.Additive`

An another option is to use [SceneManager.SetActiveScene](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.SetActiveScene.html) to change which scene you want to set as "parent scene" or the scene you want to spawn gameobjects on.

Comment: In the past, that was the correct way to go. Unity now recommends "It is recommended to avoid using DontDestroyOnLoad to persist manager GameObjects that you want to survive across scene loads. Instead, create a manager scene that has all your managers and use SceneManager.LoadScene(<path>, LoadSceneMode.Additive) and SceneManager.UnloadScene to manage your game progress.": https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/MultiSceneEditing.html